# Gitlab-agent with Helm: Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "http://localhost:8080/version": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connect: connection refused

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, continuous-integration, helm3

i installed the new gitlab agent for kubernetes cluster. This works when I use KUBECTL and gives this error when I try to deploy in Azure Cloud with Helm chart.

my .gitlab-ci.yml

```html
  variables:
  #registry variable
  REGISTRY: registry.gitlab.com
  #docker-image tag
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_SHA}
  #target variable
  TARGET: metrix9/wysiwys-ic

stages:
- build
- package
- deploy


#job to build gradle application and save the jar file in artifacts
build docker image:
  image: gradle
  stage: build
  before_script:
  - chmod +x ./gradlew
  script:
  - ./gradlew jib -Djib.to.auth.username=$CI_REGISTRY_USER -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD -Djib.from.auth.username=$CI_REGISTRY_USER -Djib.from.auth.password=$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD


# job to push file-server docker-imagedocker 
package wysiwys image:
  stage: package
  image: docker.io/library/docker
  #dependencies: 
  #  - build
  services:
  - name: docker:dind
  before_script:
  - IMAGE=${CI_REGISTRY}/${TARGET}
  - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
  - docker pull "${IMAGE}:latest" || true
  script:
  #- docker build --tag "${IMAGE}:latest" .
  - docker push "${IMAGE}:latest"
#job to package and push the file-server helm chart
package wysiwys-ic helm:
  stage: package
  image: 
    name: alpine/helm
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
  - helm repo add --username $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD  wysiwys-ci-repo https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/packages/helm/stable
  - helm plugin install https://github.com/chartmuseum/helm-push
  script:
  - helm package wysiwys-helm
  - helm cm-push ./wysiwys-helm-0.1.0.tgz  wysiwys-ci-repo

#job to install convert2pdf with helm chart
install wysiwys-ic:
  stage: deploy
  image: 
    name: alpine/helm
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
  - helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami -n Convert2pdf-repo
  script:
  - helm upgrade --install wysiwys-ci ./wysiwys-helm
```

[gitlab agent:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqknj.png)

i tryed export the KUBECONFIG and to run helm repo update in the pipeline..
but the same error comes out...

Comment: Did u resolve the issue?

Comment: and how did you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with the same issue. First use image with helm and kubectl(f.e. registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/cluster-applications) and try adding the following changes in the deployment part:

```
deploy app:
 stage: deploy-app
 variables:
  KUBE_CONTEXT: -->gitlabproject<--:-->name of the installed agent<--
 before_script:
  - if [ -n "$KUBE_CONTEXT" ]; then kubectl config use-context "$KUBE_CONTEXT"; fi
```